# CSS animation not working on SVG image in iOS devices

Tags: html, css, svg

I have one SVG image and I have added animation on it using CSS it works fine in Chrome and Mozilla, and also on Android but not working on iOS both Chrome and Safari.

The problem is that I can see the image displayed but the animation spinning is not working.

I have the following animation applied to my simple SVG:

```
<img class="img-sth"src="/img/image.svg">
```

The css code:

```
.img-sth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 16px;
  -webkit-animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
  animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin-faster { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin-faster { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin-faster { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Comment: This should only work if you actually _import_ your SVG into your HTML file, or did you include it as a `<style>` tag inside the SVG? If so, can you include a snippet of your SVG file with the code in it so we can test it in browser?

Comment: Its imported directly into HTML file, it working fine on web and android except in ios.

Comment: I understand your question, no issue. You are missing actual svg file code for us to test with. Your code does not indicate the svg will be imported, its a static image tag (no way in hell such an animation works as the rendered img is a separate unconnected document). So add more to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below see snippet where I added the `0% {}` to each `@keyframes` definition. Your code did not work for me on **macOS Safari** (desktop) either when I initially tested it so I thought it may have been an issue with how the `@keyframes` animation was defined. See [MDN docs for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

I used a placeholder image for the demo and tweaked the positioning so it was all in the viewport.

```css
.img-sth {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  -webkit-animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
  animation:spin-faster 4s linear 0.01s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin-faster {
  0% {}
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin-faster {
  0% {}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-faster { 
  0% {}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<img class="img-sth"src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x80">
```